# Listing all unique values from table in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel, I have a table where I want to list all unique values from a column in a different a row of a different sheet. Here is an example of the data I have:

[image: Example of Table]

I want to fill in cells in the other sheet so that it gives all of the different options for the favorite fruit. It would look something like this:

Apple | Banana | Grapefruit | Orange

How do I loop through the options (shown below) to make this happen?
[image: List Options]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [article](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/get-unique-items-from-list/) that explains to get *unique* values from a list. Differently, it creates a vertical list however, formula will work as horizontal as well.
However; you should add | characters by yourself, I mean by using another formula.

Unique list formula is

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($D$2:D2,$B$3:$B$9)=0),$B$3:$B$9)
```

which

- $D$2:D2 is one cell at left (or above if you want vertical list)
- $B$3:$B$9 is the range that contains all values (your actual data)

After tying formula, all you need to do is copy the formula to right cells.

Comment: The | character was used to represent that the values would be in separate cells.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly, try this:
1. Copy the fruit column & paste it somewhere else (away from the rest of the data).
2. Select the data you just copied and use Data->Remove Duplicates.  This will remove any duplicates.
3. Select the data that's left, Copy, and click on the leftmost cell of where you want the data to appear.
4. Go to *Home*->*Paste*->*Paste Special*.  Choose *Transpose* and *Values*.  Click OK.